# Vue component being destroyed twice

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

Upon logout, my component's destroy lifecycle hooks are called. Logging in from the same browser session that just logged out will cause that same component to be destroyed again before a new instance is created/mounted. This is cause issues with the library i'm using on that component.

Ex:

> First login:
>
> ```
> Component Created ID1
> Component Mounted ID1 Then logout:
> Component Before Destroy ID1
> Component Destroyed ID1 So everything so far is correct. Now log back in as a different user:
> Component Created ID1
> Component Mounted ID1
> Component Before Destroy ID 1 
> (Library fails to destroy here because things are now undefined from previous destroy
> Component Destroyed ID1
> Component Created ID2
> Component Mounted ID2
> ```

My code is doing a logout by using a vuex function. We're basically dispatching an event that does a deepClone of a clean 'default object to clear out the many vuex modules we have'
Then it does a router.push to the logout screen

I noticed that ALL our components are creating/mounting in this fashion. My component happens to fail because the library tries to access something it deleted in the last destroy.

I took out all our Keep-alives and it still occurs. Do you guys know if this lifecycle behavior is normal? It seems odd to me.

EDIT:

So I found the culprit. In our `App.Vue` we have a `<router-view v-else>`. Vue renders my component when I sign in then since the v-else fails, it tears it back down until the v-else is true again.

I tried the `v-if` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You'd be better avoid swapping the Login screen and your actual router view (with v-if/v-else) - instead, use a popup dialog or even a separate Login route.

Comment: I was able to fix it by using v-show since vue hides the component with css instead of tearing it down like the v-if/v-else. I think we do have separate routes. The main router-view is just in the App.vue

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to a v-show and it fixed the issue. Vue will just hide the component with css instead of tearing it down and remounting it.